# Dokku/Docker deploying apps fails

Tags: docker, npm, dokku

Docker noob here so bear with me.

I have a VPS with dokku configured, it has multiple apps already running.
I am trying to add a fairly complex app at present. But docker just fails with the following error.

[image]

From what I understand I need to update the packages the error is given. Problem is they are needed by some other module and I cant update it. Is a way to make docker bypass the warning and build.

Following is the content of my docker

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:6

# Create app dir
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependancy
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install

# Bundle the app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 9337

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Been trying this for a couple of days not with no success.
Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: What is in your package.json? How much RAM does your VPS has? Have you tried adding more RAM?

Comment: Its a small NodeJS based application using react/redux etc. Current VPS config is very basic 1GB ram and have not tried adding more RAM. Testing out the application for deployment, I dont see the server complaining, why do you ask about VPS ?

Comment: I believe npm process get killed with error 137 on docker is usually caused by out of memory error. You can try adding swap file to test this.

Comment: Absolutely right and thanks a ton. Tried doubling the memory after your first comment and it worked. Wish you would answer it so that I can mark it.

Comment: Moving comment as answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe npm process get killed with error 137 on docker is usually caused by out of memory error. You can try adding swap file (or add more RAM) to test this.